# No sound in laptop speakers after Bluetooth disconnect, Ubuntu Linux 17.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 17.04, alsa

I've managed to pair my Bose QC35 bluetooth headphones to my Ubuntu 17.04 laptop. The audio works fine in the headphones. However, when I disconnect them, it's seemingly impossible to get any sound out of my laptop speakers. The volume is turned up to 100%. The speakers used to work.

I've tried several solutions, like restarting bluetooth, reinstalling alsa and pulse, etc. Nothing's working.

Audio used to come back on reboot, but no more.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that the "Headphone" volume was muted, and turned down to 0. This stopped any audio from escaping the laptop speakers. You can see if you've got a similar problem by running `alsamixer` in the terminal. If anything's marked with `MM` or has the volume down to zero, that's probably it. You can use arrow keys and the `M` key to unmute and turn the volume back up.

Since this happens pretty much every time I disconnect my headphones, I've got a script here:

```
for x in `amixer controls  | grep layback` ; do amixer cset "${x}" on ; done
for x in `amixer controls  | grep layback` ; do amixer cset "${x}" 100% ; done
```

This will unmute and turn your volume to 100% for all items listed in `alsamixer`.

Spent hours tearing my hair over this and hopefully this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in 18.04 and killing pulseaudio (which automatically respawns and then rescans devices) fixes the issue without having to reboot.

```
pidof pulseaudio|xargs kill
```

Will try to kill **all** instances of pulseaudio. Under normal circumstances, two should be running, one belonging to `gdm` (or maybe `root` on older systems) and another one belonging to your own user.

So the `kill` will only kill the pulseaudio instance of your user and fail to kill the one belonging to `gdm` as well as any other that would belong to another user (which is exactly what we want...).

**ALT:** I found also another potential solution which is to [force pulse audio to rescan devices](https://superuser.com/questions/845645/pulseaudio-how-to-rescan-audio-devices/869229#869229k), but it seems to introduce more problems than it solves...